# How do I add a conditional class in React without removing other classes?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, conditional-statements

I want to add a class name to an element conditionally based on the truthiness of a state object, while maintaining the classes applied via a plugin on initial render.

**Example that doesn't work:**

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export default class CoolThing extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // This plugin sets classes to the this.refs.root DOM element when it initializes 
    $(this.refs.root).jqueryPluginIHaveToUseThatSetsClassesAndDoesStuff();
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    const classNames = classnames({
      active: this.state.active
    });

    return (
      <div ref="root" className={ classnames } onClick={ this.handleClick }></div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Same as above, but with this render also fails:**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div ref="root" className={ this.state.active ? "CoolThing active" : "CoolThing" } onClick={ this.handleClick }></div>
  )
}
```

The desired result would have the "CoolThing" class always on this example's div tag in addition to whatever classes the `jqueryPluginIHaveToUseThatSetsClassesAndDoesStuff` applied. THEN, depending upon a user action, the `active` class would also be applied and not overwrite any of the previously applied classes.

**I would like to avoid:**

- using jQuery's addClass via the `this.refs.root` reference
- adding a nested div that takes the `active` class or similar ... having themarkup structure remain intact is fairly important

Comment: Why don't you just get the classList after jquery setted them (so in the componentDidMount) and push them to the state of your component? That way they won't get lost.

Comment: Did U ever solve this? I have the same problem. Each re-render adds the new classes, and wipes out the instances from the previous render, where the classes were added.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the className to CoolThing by default, then check state.active in the render function. If you have other classes to add and you want them to persist, store them in the state, then just add them to the string template as well. This allows you to have CoolThing be the default class even if the state values have not been set yet.

```
render() {

    let jQueryClasses = this.state.jQueryClasses; 
    let active = { this.state.active ? " active": ""};
    return (
        <div ref="root" className={`CoolThing${jQueryClasses}${active}`} 
                        onClick={ this.handleClick }/>);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's essentially the same as the inline ternary. The class names assigned via the jQuery plugin are overridden the second the active state is set.

Comment: I didn't see the jQuery classes when I read over it the first time, I updated my answer to account for it :)

Comment: I see your update and raise you a, "I'm never certain what the jQuery set classes are." They are set by the plugin and theoretically could change if the plugin updates, so I wouldn't want to set them to a state controlled value nor could I as there is no callback or similar from the plugin that has that data. In all my readings, I've found an answer to this question to be breaking the fundamental structure of React, so that could very well be the case.

Comment: Couldn't you check if the jQuery classes change in componentWillReceiveProps( ), then update the state classes before each render?

Comment: I am sure you already thought about that and it doesn't work for your plugin, but I figured I should bring it up jic haha

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.active ? <div ref="root" className="CoolThing active" 
    onClick`enter code here`={ this.handleClick }></div>
    : <div ref="root" className="CoolThing" 
    onClick={ this.handleClick }></div> 
  )
}
```